Maintain search criteria after selecting items in a grid in VB.Net with JavaScript
In a user interface created in ASP.NET, I have a grid where it is possible to select a set of items. For ease of reference, I implemented a search process using JavaScript.
However, when I select an item from the grid, the search criteria disappear. This forces me to re-enter the search criteria whenever I need to select more than one item for the same criteria. How can I prevent the search criteria from disappearing after selecting an item and the grid is updated?
Grid:
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewArtifacts"  
                 runat="server" 
                 EnableViewState="true" 
                 CssClass="grid-magin" 
                 Style="margin-top: 4px; text-align: left;" 
                 Width="100%" 
                 BackColor="White" 
                 BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                 BorderStyle="None" 
                 BorderWidth="1px" 
                 CellPadding="3" 
     OnRowDataBound="gridViewArtifacts_RowDataBound"
     OnRowCreated="gridViewArtifacts_RowCreated"
     OnRowCommand="gridViewArtifacts_RowCommand">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
     <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#005AFF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
     <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />

</asp:GridView>

Search:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gridViewArtifacts').DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        searching: true, // Enable the search input
        ordering: true,  // Enable sorting
        paging: true     // Enable pagination
    });
});


You need to add the attribute ClientIDMode="Static" to the asp:GridView if you want to be able to refer to it in JavaScript as "#gridViewArtifacts". Also, $(document).ready is deprecated: see the paragraph starting with "As of jQuery 3.0" in the docs.

[Is there a typo in CssClass="grid-magin" with "magin" instead of "margin"?]

It not at all clear why you using JavaScript to try and set some attributes, but then don't really show what controls you are using for filtering.
Labels dropped into a page will NOT persist (retain their values) when set from client-side JavaScript code. However, check boxes, text boxes will retain their values when set by a user, or by JavaScript code.
I suggest that you simply place standard controls above the GridView and use them for filtering.
So, say this markup:
        <h4>View Hotels</h4>
        <div style="float:left;width:190px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select City"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"
                DataTextField="City" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            </asp:DropDownList>


        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;width:180px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Province"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboProvince" runat="server" 
                DataValueField="Province"
                DataTextField="Province" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:5px">

        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDescripiton" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;Must Have Description" />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:15px">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActiveOnly" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;Show only Active Hotels" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalconyOnly" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;Balcony" />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:112px">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWaterOnly" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;Water/Lake View" />
        </div>

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn"/>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdClear" runat="server" Text="Clear Fitler" CssClass="btn"/>
        </div>

Then right below the above filter controls, drop in your GridView. Say this:
        <div style="clear:both;height:10px">  <%-- this starts new line for grid --%>
        </div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"  
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="52%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

Now, we can filter the data, and filter control(s) will retain their state.
Hence this:

However, note how the filter controls retain their state/values.
So, I can now add more filter options to the result, say "must have description"
Hence this:

The code behind to filter the Grid is thus this:
Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    LoadByFilter


End Sub

Sub LoadByFilter()

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels"
    Dim strOrderBy As String = " ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim strWhere As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("")

    If cboCity.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        strWhere = "(City = @City)"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text
    End If

    If cboProvince.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= "(Province = @Prov)"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Prov", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboProvince.SelectedItem.Text
    End If


    ' must have description
    If chkDescripiton.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Description is not null)"
    End If

    If chkActiveOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Active = 1)"
    End If

    If chkBalconyOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (Balcony  = 1)"
    End If

    If chkWaterOnly.Checked Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= " AND "
        strWhere &= " (LakeView  = 1)"
    End If



    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strSQL &= " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If

    strSQL &= " " & strOrderBy
    cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

So, note how the code is written in such a way, that I can add 2 or 15 more controls, and the options selected are "cumulative" for the filtering. And note how each filter option is optional, but the SQL still uses parameter safe (injecting safe) SQL syntax.
So, best to simply place a set of filter controls above the GridView, since then the controls will automatically retain their state and values for each post-back. And as a FYI, those controls can be set by JavaScript, and once again, they will retain their state.
